# How to make layout like twitter new post

Tags: android, android-layout

I develop an Android Apps, then I have an inspiration like twitter new post.
Twitter new post have a layout that shrink automatically, when a soft keyboard appear..

Anybody knew where I should make like that by layout or by code.

Thanks.

Note : I Include for twitter capture :
shrink when soft keyboard appear : [appear](http://goo.gl/eZygF) or
going big when soft keyboard hidden : [hidden](http://goo.gl/HF2lz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, add this tag to your `Activity`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```